# Is it still possible to use Blue Ruby on SAP systems?

Tags: ruby, abap

Around 2011, I have heard about Blue Ruby, a way to run ruby inside the ABAP virtual machine. I cannot find any information about it. Is it still alive? Does somebody use it in development for, e.g., testing (TDD)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm hardly an authority, but reading [this blog](http://scn.sap.com/community/scripting-languages/blog/2010/12/18/blue-ruby-now-available-on-code-exchange), I'd say...

> in the course of our everlasting re-organization - it is true that the
>   only thing that's constant at SAP is change - **Blue Ruby, the research
>   project, is no longer**.

...alive is probably not a word I'd use, no...